# Links under "Help" are broken for guest users

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, 500-server-error, anonymous-visitors

Almost all links in the Help Center (network-wide) are broken when one's not logged in.

Some examples to try: <sup>(use Incognito, or the like)</sup>

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
- https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask

This is what I get if I'm browsing anonymously:

[image: Error Path]

Comment: Strangely enough the index page https://stackoverflow.com/help does work.

Comment: @rene Yes, along with some other pages like [CoC](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) but most of the other links are broken.

Comment: I see the errors - I'm on it.

Comment: A fix is in and Jarrod's doing me a solid to build it out shortly - should be fixed in the next ~ 15.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whelp, that's my fault. A refactor earlier today on the way to .NET Core broke this specific path - sorry about that!

A fix has been deployed. Nothing interesting here unfortunately so I won't go in depth - just missed an anonymous check in a permissions check.